# Setting the correct width of a child window

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015, dock, mdichild

I have a parent window that has a panel on the left hand side into which some buttons are placed. There is also a splitter added, so that the user can adjust the size of this panel. When a user presses one of the buttons, a form should appear on the right hand size - defaulting to the width of the remaining area of the window. In order to work out how wide this child form needs to be, I have taken the client width and subtracted the width of the panel and the splitter from this, however it is always slightly too big. I can simply subtract an additional 4 from the calculation to get it to work - but this feels unstable to me, as I don't know where those 4 pixels have come form! How do I calculate this correctly. My Code is below.

```
Dim xPos As Integer = Me.Panel1.Width + Me.Splitter1.Width
Dim yPos As Integer = 0
Dim childFormWidth As Integer = Me.ClientSize.Width - xPos
Dim childFormHeight As Integer = 200

myChildForm.Show()
myChildForm.Location = New Point(xPos, yPos)
myChildForm.Size = New Size(ChildFormWidth, myHeight)
```

Thanks Paul.

Comment: is it possible there is 2px of padding on either side that you're not accounting for?

Comment: What about using Me.Splitter1.Panel2.Width. Could the extra size be from the form border?

Comment: Tyler, there is no Padding on anything - I've just double checked. I don't think this makes a difference, but I've also changed the default margins on the panel and splitter to 0 (originally set to {3,3,3,3}).

Comment: FloatingKiwi, there is no Panel2 - are you suggesting that I create one?

Comment: For test purposes I added a new panel, this time docked to the bottom, and used the width of this to determine the width of the child table should be. Interestingly this gives me the same results - i.e. it is 4 pixels too wide - or at least the horizontal scroll bar always appears!